# How does SKU number is generating in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, sku

I would like to know how Magento 2 generates SKU number?

While checking Mask for SKU in admin, there is filled as `{{name}}`. So when I create a product, the SKU automatically filled with the product name I have given.

Could anyone please help me to understand SKU in detail?

Comment: Everything you have written in the question. What do you want to understand?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, By default SKU mask is product name. What If I want it to customize as per the need?

Comment: I tried to change it to {{price}} etc. and found it working. It means it works for the attributes.